# Separate a string in @currentfield by empty space

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm currently using SharePoint column formatting JSON to turn a field's string entry into a URL using the following:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

Since `@currentField` contains a `filename.pdf` (file size)
I will end up with broken link were the file size is included in the link, something like
http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/my-file-name_pdf.pdf%20(338%20KB)
Can I generate a link which ends with *.pdf or space?

Comment: Hi @Omal, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any space in `filename.pdf`, you can use the expression like below to extract the filename before space between file name & file size:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
     "target": "_blank",
     "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + substring(@currentField, 0, indexOf(@currentField, ' '))"
  }
}
```

**OR**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
     "target": "_blank",
     "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + substring(@currentField, 0, indexOf(@currentField, ' ('))"
  }
}
```

**Documentation**: [Formatting syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators)

Comment: Hi @Omal, does this work for you?